# Insert a 2x2 matrix into a 5x5 matrix

Tags: equations, matrices

I need to insert a 2x2 matrix evenly into the 4th and 5th rows and the 4th and 5th columns of a 5x5 matrix. My code needs tweaking.

```
\begin{equation*}
    a_1=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & & {\begin{bmatrix} & b & \end{bmatrix}}\\
        0 & 0 & 0 &
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or maybe with `nicematrix`. It does require an extra package (which in turn loads other stuff, most prominently Ti*k*Z), yet the spacing between the columns does not get modified and you have full control over all aspects of the appearance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
a_1=\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \phantom{0} & \phantom{0}\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \phantom{0} & \phantom{0}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fit=(mymatrix-4-4)(mymatrix-5-5),inner sep=-0.2ex,text height=1.2em] (f){$b$};
\draw[thick] ([xshift=0.5ex]f.south west)-| (f.north west) -- ++ (0.5ex,0)
([xshift=-0.5ex]f.south east)-| (f.north east) -- ++ (-0.5ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `bmatrix` for the 2x2 matrix I used `matrix`. But it is only a personal preference and can be exchanged without problems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    a_1=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}  
            1 & 0 & 0\\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0
        \end{matrix} & 
        \begin{matrix} 
            0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0
        \end{matrix}\\
        \begin{matrix}
            0 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0
        \end{matrix} & 
        \begin{matrix} & b & \end{matrix}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Result with `matrix`:

[image: matrix]

Result with `bmatrix`:

[image: bmatrix]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    a_1=
  \left[
   \begin{blockarray}{@{\,}ccccc@{\:}}
\bigstrut[t]
           1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
        \begin{block}{@{\,}ccc[\BAmulticolumn{2}{!{}c!{}}@{\:}]}
            0 & 0 & 0 & \multirow{2}{*}{b}\\
           0 & 0 & 0 & \\
        \end{block}
\BAnoalign{\vskip -7ex}
    \end{blockarray}\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]